# Spring Actuator Prometheus: visualize available metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, documentation, micrometer

I have an endpoint `/api/actuator/prometheus` that returns registered metrics in Prometheus format.

Is it possible to format this document prettily and host it on GitLab Pages?
I want to do something similar as Open API does but for available Prometheus metrics.

Comment: An important thing to keep in mind: metrics are only created if they are used so if you have metrics for an http endpoint, you need to call that endpoint  if you want metrics to be shown on the Prometheus endpoint.

Another thing worth mentioning: we are experimenting with auto-documenting meters (and more) in Micrometer 1.10 (Spring Boot 3.0), you might want to follow that effort.

Comment: Also, the Open API is a little different since for that you don’t need to call the endpoints but if you want metrics showing up on the prometheus endpoint, you need to use them. Spring REST Docs might closer https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs or a single page app that calls the Prometheus endpoint on-demand and shows what is there live.